# Why I can't append an integer value before writing it in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

What I am trying to do is assigning every pixel value in csv file. there is 270000 pixels in every image. when i try to append the integer value, it does generate the csv file but not this integer value in the end, in this case in "kelas".
Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

kelas0 = 0
kelas1 = 1
kelas2 = 2

number = []
image_list = []
tags = []
pixels = []

for i in range(0,270000):
    tags.append("pixel_{}".format(i))

tags.insert(0,"index")
tags.append("kelas")

for i in range(0, 190):
    number.append(i)

load_dir = "C:\\Users\\orusx\\Documents\\ITS\\TA\\Program\\dataset"
catagories = ["Kualitas A", "Kualitas B", "Kualitas C"]

with open('image_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(tags)
    for kelas, catagories in enumerate(os.listdir(load_dir)):
        print(catagories)
        for image in os.listdir(os.path.join(load_dir, catagories)):
            new_path = os.path.join(load_dir,catagories)
            image_list.append(os.path.join(new_path, image))
            #print(image)
            #print(image_list)
    for index, gambar in enumerate(image_list):
        print(type(index))
        img = cv.imread(gambar)
        img_array = list(img.flatten())
        for pixel in img_array:
            pixels.append(pixel)
        pixels.insert(0, index)

        if index <= 62:
            pixels.append(kelas0)
            writer.writerow(pixels)
        elif 62<index<=125:
            pixels.append(kelas1)
            writer.writerow(pixels)
        elif 125<index<=188:
            pixels.append(kelas2)
            writer.writerow(pixels)

        pixels = []
```

Comment: `kelas` is your last element in `tags`, what you meaning "not this integer value in the end"

Comment: the focus is on the last for loop. what i want to do is at the end of every list that indexed below 62 will get value 1 and so on. but when i try to run it, there is no value what i want in the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. The fact that the data is being cut when I load them using excel, makes me scratch my head for hours. I try to append it using a string with a special indication to troubleshoot this problem and didn't find any my special indication when I try to search it in excel. but when I open it in notepad, it found my special indication. so the problem is actually in excel. I'm so sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Are these greyscale images? Can you add a link to a sample image? Perhaps show a worked example with a simple 5x5 pixel image

Comment: `categories` is a list of 3 folder names but you then overwrite it with the filename found in `load_dir` ?